# How do you check the browser's user agent in a JSP page using JSTL, EL?

Tags: java, jsp, browser, cross-browser, user-agent

I need to check the browser's user-agent to see if it is IE6. However I shouldn't use scriptlets (we have a strict no scriptlets policy) to do this.

Currently I use

```
<%
String ua = request.getHeader( "User-Agent" );
boolean isMSIE = ( ua != null && ua.indexOf( "MSIE" ) != -1 );
%>

<% if( isMSIE ){ %>
<div>
<% } %>
```

What is the cleanest way to do this using JSTL, EL, etc and not scriptlets?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
<c:set var="browser" value="${header['User-Agent']}" scope="session"/>
```

Answer (score 21):

```
<c:if test="${fn:contains(header['User-Agent'],'MSIE')}"></c:if>
```

Comment: <c:if test="${fn:contains(header['User-Agent'],'MSIE')}"></c:if>

Comment: Zoltan, you need to add four spaces to the beginning of code so that it's displayed properly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [spring-mobile](http://projects.spring.io/spring-mobile/) framework you can use following to check device type

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 
    <c:choose> 
        <c:when test="${currentDevice.normal}"><p>"Welcome desktop user"</p> </c:when>
        <c:when test="${currentDevice.mobile}"><p>"Welcome mobile user"</p>  </c:when>
        <c:when test="${currentDevice.tab}"><p>"Welcome tab user"</p> </c:when>
    </c:choose>
```