# Detect Javafx webview

Tags: javascript, html, javafx, webview

So I am creating a java desktop program. This programs goes to a authentication webpage running on jsp. And does so using the javafx webview(which runs on WebKit)

My question is how can I detect the if the webpage is being accessed using java webview then if not disconnect or redirect the client in order to help lower spam authentication request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JavaFX WebView allows you to set a user agent string, using the [user agent property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#userAgentProperty) on the WebEngine.  You can use this to set the user agent to anything that you wish.  Then when the WebView client requests a web page, it will supply this value in the user agent header.  Your server code can query the user agent header and then take whatever action it deems necessary based upon the result.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23214913/version-of-webkit-in-javafx-8-webview), the default output for the user agent string was:

```
User Agent:     Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.44 (KHTML, like Gecko) JavaFX/8.0 Safari/537.44
```

As noted in the WebEngine documentation, this value can change between JavaFX versions and operating systems.  Most likely, the default will always include the text `JavaFX`, so you could just check on the server if the user agent string contains the text `JavaFX`.  Otherwise, if you want to be super-sure, then you can code your JavaFX client to explicitly set the user agent string to a value which you check on your server.

To see how to check a user agent in a JSP, refer to:

- [How do you check the browser's user agent in a JSP page using JSTL, EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968800/how-do-you-check-the-browsers-user-agent-in-a-jsp-page-using-jstl-el)

Which would indicate that you would write something like this:

```
<c:if test="${fn:contains(header['User-Agent'],'JavaFX')}"></c:if>
```